# Speeding up pymongo inserts in this loop

Tags: python, mongodb, insert, pymongo

I need to integrate just over half a terabyte of data into MongoDB (about 525GB).

They are visits to my website, each line of the file is a tab delimited string

This is my main loop:

```
f = codecs.open(directoryLocation+fileWithData, encoding='utf-8')
count = 0 #start the line counter

for line in f:
    print line
    line = line.split('\t')

    document = {
        'date': line[0],     # a date as a string
        'user_id': line[1],  # a string 
        'datetime': line[2], # a unix timestamp
        'url': line[3],      # a fairly long string
        'ref_url': line[4],  # another fairly long string
        'date_obj': datetime.utcfromtimestamp(float(line[2])) #a date object
    }

    Visits.insert(document)

    #line integration time/stats
    count = count + 1 #increment the counter
    now = datetime.now()
    diff = now - startTime
    taken = diff.seconds
    avgPerLine = float(taken) / float(count)
    totalTimeLeft = (howManyLinesTotal-count) * avgPerLine
    print "Time left (mins): " + str(totalTimeLeft/60) #output the stats
    print "Avg per line: " + str(avgPerLine)
```

I'm currently getting about 0.00095 seconds per line, which is REALLY slow considering the amount of data I need to integrate.

I̶'̶m̶ ̶g̶o̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶e̶n̶a̶b̶l̶e̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶p̶y̶m̶o̶n̶g̶o̶ ̶C̶ ̶v̶e̶r̶s̶i̶o̶n̶ ̶s̶i̶n̶c̶e̶ ̶I̶ ̶c̶h̶e̶c̶k̶e̶d̶ ̶t̶h̶a̶t̶ ̶p̶y̶m̶o̶n̶g̶o̶.̶h̶a̶s̶_̶c̶(̶)̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶F̶a̶l̶s̶e̶.̶
PyMongo C version now enabled, its hovering about 0.0007 or 0.0008 seconds per line. Still pretty slow. 3.3Ghz intel i3 with 16GB ram.

What else will be bottlenecking this loop? I pretty much have to have the 3 different dates, but could ask to get rid of one if its totally slowing things down

The stats are really useful because it shows me how much longer is left during these huge integrations. However, I guess their calculations might be slowing things down on a large scale? Could it be all the printing to terminal?

EDIT:

I've put the loop minus the actual insert into cProfile and this is the result of 99999 sample lines:

```
         300001 function calls in 32.061 CPU seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000   32.061   32.061 <string>:1(<module>)
        1   31.326   31.326   32.061   32.061 cprofiler.py:14(myfunction)
   100000    0.396    0.000    0.396    0.000 {built-in method now}
    99999    0.199    0.000    0.199    0.000 {built-in method utcfromtimestamp}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
    99999    0.140    0.000    0.140    0.000 {method 'split' of 'str' objects}
```

EDIT 2: Solved by Matt Tenenbaum - the solution- only output to the terminal once every 10,000 or so lines.

Comment: Try the C version *then* come back. Measuring against the Python-only version is pointless. And the Python profiler tells you what is slow. Where is your profile?

Comment: Indentation now fixed. 

I've installed the C version and its the same speed-ish. Running at around 0.0008 seconds / line.

Comment: Added profile - what do you think?

Comment: On the mongo side, is the collection you're inserting into heavily indexed? Indexed at all? If so, could you insert the data and then index after?

Comment: Also, I imagine there are quite a few lines in your 0.5TB of data; surely you don't need progress output for all of them. Show progress for every 1000 lines by qualifying the whole last chunk of code with `if count % 1000 == 0` (or whatever number of inserts is reasonable between feedback updates).

Comment: The mongo side isn't indexed at all - just wanging everything in at the moment. I'll try the 1000 lines idea and get back to you!

Comment: Matt - your solution was awesome! I stopped outputting each line to the terminal, and am now just doing 1 in 10,000. The speed is down to 0.0001008 sec per line. wow! Can you write this as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables I'm glad that helped. (As requested, I made it an actual answer.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Zagorulkin says, it's important not to be doing a bunch of indexing while inserting, so make sure there are no operative indexed.

Beyond that, you probably want to limit the feedback to every 1000 lines (or some useful number based on how many lines you have to input, or how much feedback you want). Instead of doing all the calculations to produce the feedback on each iteration, change the last block of your code to qualify it against `count` so that it only passes the test once every 1000 iterations:

```
    #line integration time/stats
    count = count + 1 #increment the counter
    if count % 1000 == 0:
        now = datetime.now()
        diff = now - startTime
        taken = diff.seconds
        avgPerLine = float(taken) / float(count)
        totalTimeLeft = (howManyLinesTotal-count) * avgPerLine
        print "Time left (mins): " + str(totalTimeLeft/60) #output the stats
        print "Avg per line: " + str(avgPerLine)
```

Again, 1000 might not be the right number  for you, but something like that will prevent a lot of this work from happening, while still giving you the feedback you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks! I set it to count % 100000 and its working wonderfully, down to 0.0001 ~ 0.00009 per line so I should have all the data integrated over the weekend ^_^

Answer (score 3):

1. `Delete all indexes` which exists in collection
2. If you have a replication than set `w=0, j=0`
3. Use `bulk inserts`

Some performance tests: http://www.arangodb.org/2012/09/04/bulk-inserts-mongodb-couchdb-arangodb